# PANDAS - how to color entire row based on value in Index

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have the following MultiIndex Dataframe:

```py
pt = df[df['Top Task Work Type'].isin(['Customer Billable','Customer Non-Billable', 'Work at risk'])].pivot_table(
    index = ['Resource id', 'End Customer Name', 'Top Task Work Type'],
    columns= ['Fiscal Quarter','Fiscal Week In Qtr Num Int'],
    values= ['Total Hours'],
    aggfunc = {'Total Hours' : np.sum}
)
```

as you can see above, I create a Pivot table from an excel sheet using 'Top Task Work Type' as my filter. Pivot table it creates has a 40 columns.

Excel output looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFD5J.jpg

I want to highlight in red (color) all rows that have value "Customer Non-Billable" like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySq7L.jpg

I have tried to apply style to dt in several ways like:

```py
def highlight_col(x):
    #copy df to new - original data are not changed
    df = x.copy()
    #set by condition
    mask = pt.index.get_level_values('Top Task Work Type') == 'Customer Non-Billable'
    df.loc[mask, :] = 'background-color: yellow'
    df.loc[~mask,:] = 'background-color: ""'
    return df    

pt.style.apply(highlight_col, axis=1)
```

without any success. I have been able to color row based on column for certain value, but I want to color all rows that have a value of "Customer Non-Billable"

any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: An [mcve] would be helpful for apply styling to desired input data.  Answers below do not reflect the desired pivot table with multiindex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is styling using the Pandas > 0.20 strategy.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO
import xlsxwriter
import xlwt
import openpyxl

csvdata = StringIO("""date,LASTA,LASTB,LASTC
1999-03-15,-2.5597,8.20145,16.900
1999-03-17,2.6375,8.12431,17.125
1999-03-18,2.6375,-8.27908,16.950
1999-03-19,2.6634,8.54914,17.325
1999-04-06,2.8537,7.63703,17.750""")

df = pd.read_csv(csvdata, sep=",", index_col="date", parse_dates=True, infer_datetime_format=True)

def color_negative_red(val):
    color = 'red' if val < 0 else 'white'
    return 'background-color: %s' % color            

df.style.\
    applymap(color_negative_red).\
    to_excel('styletest.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

Styling with the XlsxWriter Strategy.  Maybe this provides easier access to the data to be styled.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO
import xlsxwriter
import xlwt
import openpyxl

csvdata = StringIO("""date,LASTA,LASTB,LASTC
1999-03-15,-2.5597,8.20145,16.900
1999-03-17,2.6375,8.12431,17.125
1999-03-18,2.6375,-8.27908,16.950
1999-03-19,2.6634,8.54914,17.325
1999-04-06,2.8537,7.63703,17.750""")

df = pd.read_csv(csvdata, sep=",", index_col="date", parse_dates=True, infer_datetime_format=True)

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("styletest.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Add some cell formats.
format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.00'})
format2 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0%'})
format3 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'yellow'})

# Set the column width and format.
worksheet.set_column('B:B', 18, format2)
worksheet.set_row(2, 5, format3)

# Set the format but not the column width.
worksheet.set_column('C:C', None, format2)

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Going after a subset of the data in a `DataFrame` with a `Multiindex`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A0','A1'], ['B0','B1','B2','B3']])
columns = ['foo', 'bar']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape((len(midx), len(columns))),index=midx, columns=columns)

def style(val):
    return 'background-color: yellow'

idx = pd.IndexSlice[:, 'B0':'B1']
print(df.loc[idx,:])

df.style.applymap(style, subset=idx).to_excel('styletest.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

Yet the specified `IndexSlice` isn't working.  But this should be the pattern.

Comment: Passing a valid indexer through applymap() on the subset keyword is supposed to work.  https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19861

Comment: I'm stuck on gettting an `IndexSlice` working with the `apply` or `applymap` `subset` keyword.

Comment: Thanks Rich, I followed your recommendation and used styling with XLSwriter instead of trying to do it with PANDAS

Comment: Would really love to get `IndexSlice` working though!

Answer (score 0):

I made it worked using XMLwriter

I first created style to use:

```
########## Format definition for CAP #########
format_cap = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE',
                               'font_color': '#9C0006'})
```

Then applied it:

```
worksheet_all.conditional_format('C5:BC500', {'type': 'formula',
                                         'criteria': '=LEFT($C5, 250)="Customer Non-Billable"', 
                                          'format': format_cap})
```

it worked